# document.cookie() function is not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set cookie in JavaScript when the user inputs in the textbox but it seems like its not working somehow. When I try to alert or console.log. I get "" value. Kindly help me  with this.

**HTML code:**

```
<form action="confirm.html" id="interestForm" onsubmit="storeInHidden1()">
  <input type="text" name="userName">
  <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

**JS code:**

```
function storeInHidden1(){
   const queryString = window.location.search;
   const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
   var queryStringDetails = urlParams.get("userName");
   document.cookie = "name=" + queryStringDetails;
   alert(document.cookie);
}
```

Comment: Any chance the given cookie is set to `HttpOnly` ? it will make it inaccessible to `document.cookie API`

Comment: document.cookie is not a function.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set cookie and get cookie with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript)

Comment: Thanks @OrelEraki for the response. I am working on the local host.

Comment: @Iwrestledabearonce. No this doesnt seem to work. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Have you checked whether your localhost setup is set to allow cookies? [httpCookies setting in the web.config maybe?]

Comment: @AHaworth thanks for the response. Yea they are enabled.

Comment: "document.cookie() function is not working in Javascript" - 1: `document.cookie` is not meant to be used as a function. 2: I don't see you calling `document.cookie()` anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### The problem

Setting a cookie like

```js
document.cookie = "name=" + variable
```

is according to [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp) a valid way of doing it. However the problem is that you are trying to acces url parameters that don't exist, which is the reason why your cookies are empty.
Suppose on `example.com/index.html` you have the following form:

```html
<form action="confirm.html" id="interestForm" onsubmit="storeInHidden1()">
  <input type="text" name="userName">
  <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```

`onsubmit` the code runs the function `storeInHidden1()` which tries to get the `window.location.search` which is still empty because nothing in your code sets the `window.location.search` on `example.com/index.html`.

Next according to `action="confirm.html"` in the form, all of the data is send with a `GET` request to (for example) `example.com/confirm.html`. This url has now the parameters of `?userName=JohnDoe`. If you were now to run `storeInHidden1` on this page you would in fact get some content in your cookie.

### The solution

In order to save the username in a cookie on `index.html` you would only have to change the code in `storeInHidden1`. Instead of getting the username out of the url you would then get it directly from the form with `document.getElementsByName("userName")[0].value`. The full code can be found below:

```js
function storeInHidden1() {
  var user = document.getElementsByName("userName")[0].value;
  document.cookie = "name=" + user;
  alert(document.cookie);
}
```

```html
<form action="confirm.html" id="interestForm" onsubmit="storeInHidden1()">
  <input type="text" name="userName">
  <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>
```